# spring roo conditional database request

Tags: java, database, spring-roo

Is there any automatic way to create conditional database request with Spring roo? For example, I have Book class and this class has page attribute. I want to list books which has more than 100 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to generate it automatically, but you can create it on your `Book` class. By example:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class Book {


   public int pages;

   // ...
   // ...
   // ...
   public static List<Book> findLargeBooks() {

        return entityManager().createQuery(
            "Select o from Book o where o.pages > 100", Book.class).getResultList();

   }


}
```